# SQL code efficiency & compiling issues with Microsoft Access

Tags: mysql, ms-access

Is there a way to setup this code in a more efficient way? I'm trying to filter through several different criteria and I'm having a hard time even compiling the code. Also the reason for all the IS NULL is that I want to make it so that if no information is inputted, for it to just accept all data.

Anyone got any tips for how I can optimize this code? Specifically the **WHERE** section. Is there a if then statement that I could use? Or an Index?

```
SELECT [Table Material Label].Serial, [Table Material Label].[Date Recieved], [Table Material Label].MaterialDescription, [Table Material Label].MaterialCode, [Table Material Label].Supplier, 

[Table Material Label].[Lot Number], [Table Material Label].Weight, [Table Material Label].Quantity, [Table Material Label].[Purchase Order Number], [Table Material Label].[Received By], [Table Material Label].[Checked in By], [Table Material Label].[Total Weight]

FROM [Table Material Label]
WHERE (([Table Material Label].[Date Recieved])>=[Forms]![Report Generator]![Text6] 
    AND ([Table Material Label].[Date Recieved])<=[Forms]![Report Generator]![Text7]) 

    AND ([Table Material Label].MaterialDescription = [Forms]![Report Generator]![repMaterial] 
     OR [Forms]![Report Generator]![repMaterial] IS NULL)

    AND ([Table Material Label].MaterialCode = [Forms]![Report Generator]![repItem] 
     OR [Forms]![Report Generator]![repItem] IS NULL)

    AND ([Table Material Label].[Lot Number] = [Forms]![Report Generator]![repLot] 
     OR [Forms]![Report Generator]![repLot] IS NULL)

    AND ([Table Material Label].Weight = [Forms]![Report Generator]![repWeight] 
     OR [Forms]![Report Generator]![repWeight] IS NULL)

    AND ([Table Material Label].Quantity = [Forms]![Report Generator]![repQuantity] 
     OR [Forms]![Report Generator]![RepQuantity] IS NULL)

    AND ([Table Material Label].[Purchase Order Number] = [Forms]![Report Generator]![repPurchaseOrder] 
     OR [Forms]![Report Generator]![repPurchaseOrder] IS NULL)

    AND ([Table Material Label].[Received By] = [Forms]![Report Generator]![repRecBy] 
     OR [Forms]![Report Generator]![repRecBy] IS NULL)

    AND ([Table Material Label].[Checked in By] = [Forms]![Report Generator]![repCheckBy] 
     OR [Forms]![Report Generator]![repCheckBy] IS NULL)

    AND ([Table Material Label].[Total Weight] = [Forms]![Report Generator]![repTotalWeight] 
     OR [Forms]![Report Generator]![repTotalWeight] IS NULL)

    AND ([Table Material Label].Supplier = [Forms]![Report Generator]![Supp] 
     OR [Forms]![Report Generator]![Supp] IS NULL)


ORDER BY [Table Material Label].[Date Recieved], [Table Material Label].MaterialDescription, [Table Material Label].MaterialCode, [Table Material Label].Supplier;
```

Comment: for all the or's consider: `AND ([Table Material Label].MaterialDescription = Nz([Forms]![Report Generator]![repMaterial], [Table Material Label].MaterialDescription)` thereby eliminating all the ors... not sure if it will help w/o testing.  Essential if the form repMaterial is null then use the material description instead that way in essence 1=1 and the or's can be omitted.

Comment: xQbert, this worked extremely well. Thanks. Updating the main post.

Answer (score 0):

Your code for `WHERE` is simplest, at least I don't know any simpler solutions. You have two conditions per each criteria, this is minimum if you need to show all records for empty criteria. Only one problem with this code - you should keep the query in SQL text format. If you switch to query builder, it will make total mess, almost unreadable. As SQL text it's not complicated, you should not have any problems with running this query, it won't be compiled. Of course you should have indexes for each field in `WHERE` clause for better performance.