# Access criteria not equal to zero

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I am having trouble filtering out the zero fields using the query below. Many records which have a zero in the "3 Yr Average" or "Comp Usage" fields are still included in the results.

[image: Query]

Removing the "<>0" or "Is Not Null" criteria change nothing in the output table. Access is generating the following SQL:

```
SELECT 
[active plant parts made from dept produced components usage].assembly_item_no, 
[active plant parts made from dept produced components usage].component_item_no, 
[active plant parts made from dept produced components usage].component_qty, 
[active plant parts made from dept produced components usage].[3 yr average], 
[active plant parts made from dept produced components usage].[comp usage], 
noetix_sys_invus_category_all.[a$cat$item_type] 
INTO   [department component usage and assembly type] 
FROM   [active plant parts made from dept produced components usage] 
       INNER JOIN noetix_sys_invus_category_all 
               ON 
[active plant parts made from dept produced components usage].assembly_item_no = 
noetix_sys_invus_category_all.[a$item$item_number] 
WHERE  ( ( ( 
[active plant parts made from dept produced components usage].[3 yr average] 

) 
<> 0 ) 
  AND ( ( 
  [active plant parts made from dept produced components usage].[comp usage] ) 
<> 0 ) 
  AND ( ( noetix_sys_invus_category_all. [a$cat$item_type] ) = "aft" ) ) 
 OR ( ( ( 
[active plant parts made from dept produced components usage].[3 yr average] 
) 
IS NOT NULL ) 
  AND ( ( 
  [active plant parts made from dept produced components usage].[comp usage] 
        ) 
    IS NOT NULL ) 
  AND ( ( noetix_sys_invus_category_all.[a$cat$item_type] ) = "aft+" ) ) 
OR (( ( noetix_sys_invus_category_all.[a$cat$item_type] ) = "oem" )) 
OR (( ( noetix_sys_invus_category_all.[a$cat$item_type] ) = "oem+" )) 
ORDER  BY 
[active plant parts made from dept produced components usage].[3 yr average] DESC, 
[active plant parts made from dept produced components usage].[comp usage] DESC, 
noetix_sys_invus_category_all.[a$cat$item_type];
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe simplify using `in` and `nz`.  I say maybe because I'm not entirely sure what expected result you are after.

```
WHERE nz([Active Plant Parts Made From Dept Produced Components Usage].[3 Yr Average],0)<>0
  AND nz([Active Plant Parts Made From Dept Produced Components Usage].[Comp Usage],0)<>0 
  AND NOETIX_SYS_INVUS_CATEGORY_ALL.[A$CAT$ITEM_TYPE] in("AFT","AFT+","OEM","OEM+")
```

Or statements are generally expensive for the engine to evaluate; so if we can do multiple evaluations at once using an IN we get a performance benefit.

Using `nz` we convert nulls to 0's which are then excluded from the results.   so in situations where both 3 yr average or comp usage is null or zero, then the record is excluded.

Comment: IsNull doesn't work like that in Access, you would need to use Nz(Expression,0)

Comment: I knew that... used it on [Thursday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45222393/sql-code-efficiency-compiling-issues-with-microsoft-access#comment77411148_45222393)... just don't play w/ access enough to remember that..  Thanks for that.  I just wish coalesce was supported.  it's my defactor change null to something for most engines.  and case when not...

Comment: Also note:  As this is a create table statement, the order by is unnecessary; and just eats time.  the select from the table created should have the order by.  the order of the inserts doesn't really help anything.

Answer (score 1):

Reading across a Criteria row is an AND statement, so, for example, `Is Not Null` only applies for "AFT+".

Use a single row and the And (or Or) keywords. Examples (typed in a single cell):

```
<>0 And Is Not Null

"X" Or "Y" Or "Z"
```

or repeat the first expression for every "X", "Y", etc., row.